# 'Collection' object is not callable error in pymongo with process Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pymongo

Using the code below causes:

```
'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '__getnewargs__' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

The code : 
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    db = MongoClient(ip,port)

```
def f(cursor, arg):
    for doc in cursor:
       ...

p = Pool(4)
for arg in args:
    cursor = db[dbName][collName].find()
    p.apply_async(f,[cursor, arg])

db.close()
```

Can't figure out what is the problem and how to debug the code.

Full Traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1489, in __call__
    self.__name.split(".")[-1])
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '__getnewargs__' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Comment: At what line does the error occur?

Comment: updated with full traceback

Comment: Is `Pool` imported from the top level `multiprocessing` package, or from some other module (like `multiprocessing.dummy` or something in pymongo)?

Comment: The `__getnewargs__` method is used for pickling, so it seems there may be an issue pickling the `Collection` object (which is required to send it between processes when using `multiprocessing`). There's an old bug that's similar reported against `mongoengine` here: https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/135.

Comment: @Blckknght Pool is imported from multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your use of `cursor`.
The `Collection.find` method returns a `Cursor` object which is a consumable. ([http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.**getitem**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.__getitem__)) I don't know if this is the cause of the exception but it is surely a problem.

Two solutions for you:

1. Explicitly pull the documents before threading using a `[:]` or `list`
2. Give the cursor in `apply_async` and clone the cursor using `clone` method (http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.clone)